# Which SearchView is good for higher API?

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using RecyclerView and SearchView.

but I'don't know what to use.

In Android Devloper,
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView

there are
`Note: This class is included in the support library for compatibility with API level 7 and higher. If you're developing your app for API level 11 and higher only, you should instead use the framework SearchView class.`

so I thought I have to use another SearchView.
android.widget.SearchView

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

However, android.support.v7.widget.SearchView is added in version 25.1.0 and android.widget.SearchView is added in API level 11.

Which SearchView is suitable for recent API?
I'm using API 26 emulator. (I will update my app for higher API later ex.API27,API28...)
Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Use android.widget.SearchView which has more flexibility than the support version.

The delay in upgrades combined with regular new releases makes compatibility an important issue in Android programming.

Support library is quickly updated when new features are added to the  API but still lacks many features that are not backwards compatible.

If google explicitly says to use android.widget.SearchView, then you should use it.

Whereas some APIs like the RecyclerView still uses v7 support version because Google choose to provide new as well as backward compatible features in the support version.

Therefore, you should check the lint warnings and consider the official Developer guides in case any API gets depreciated.

Comment: This is exactly backwards.  You should NEVER use a widget directly when there's a support version.  The support version is the one that is backwards compatible, and receives more frequent updates than the built in one (which is only updated if your OS is updated.  The support version can be updated by the developer to the most recent anytime the developer wishes, and Google can put out a new one at any time (unlike an OS upgrade, where phones wait years or never get one).  It also ensures that all devices run the same code and have the same bugs.

Comment: This is also why Google is moving twoards putting everything it can into the support library instead of adding them to the framework.  Going forward anything that can be done in software will be found in support libraries (now the androidx libraries).

Comment: I have specified that google does update the support libraries faster in my answer. But for this particular case, official Developer Guides says that you should not use the support version.https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView . Hence, at the end of my answer, I clearly said that you should check out the official guides in case something is depreciated. Please don't down vote answers without checking.